# How can I remove a file on uninstall and not on an upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.9

I want use the following declaration to remove a file on uninstall:

```
<Component Id="RemoveFilesComponent" Directory="BIN" KeyPath="yes" Guid="MY-GUID-HERE">
    <RemoveFile Id="RemoveTxtFile" Directory="BIN" Name="file.txt" On="uninstall" />
</Component>
```

**Problem:** The attribute `On="uninstall"` also removes the file during an upgrade.

I use the following declaration to enable upgrades of the software:

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of $(var.AppName) is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
```

How can I rewrite `On="uninstall"` in the element `RemoveFile`, that the file will not be removed (replaced) on an upgrade?

**Additional Info:** The file `file.txt` must be explicit removed by the declaration `RemoveFile`, because it is an generated file by the app.

Comment: Sounds similar to this question from a few days ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405678/how-can-i-keep-my-config-file-on-a-majorupgrade/36407264

Comment: @jbudreau: "How can I remove a file on uninstall and not on an upgrade?" and "How can I keep my config file on a MajorUpgrade?" are totally different questions.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to write a custom action to delete the file, and condition it on "$<component>=2 And Not UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE". The RemoveFile table doesn't have a way to detect uninstall vs. upgrade.

Comment: @jbudreau: thank you very much for your answer. I will try this approach.